# THREE.js text not showing with out any errors

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is my shape geometry, material and mesh it is pulling no errors yet when I run the code the text doesn't seem to appear does anyone know why?

```
var shapeText = new THREE.TextGeometry("TheOriginal", {font: 'helvetiker'});
var wrapper = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
var words = new THREE.Mesh(shapeText, wrapper);
scene.add(words);
console.log(words.position);
```

Comment: we would need to know how your camera is defined and where it is looking at? if you place a cube at the same place where your textgeometry is, is it visible?

Comment: camera.position.x = 2;
    camera.position.y = 2;
    camera.position.z = 2;
    camera.lookAt(words.position);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your camera away from object

```
camera.position.set(300,300,300);
camera.lookAt(words.position);
```

You are too close to the text. Actually your camera positioned between letters or inside the text mesh and looks outside from the text.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think that the words geometry was that big by default.